# why if i want add another function showing th message error "expected an indented error"

Tags: python

if i add some function why expected an indented block whats wrong my spacing  or tab my code

```
def coverage ():


#fungsi througput
def througput ():
    print("---------------menghitung througput Tower-------------------")

    print ("====Plih band====")
    print("[]. 1.5 MHz, 6 RB")
    print("[]. 3 MHz, 15 RB")
    print("[]. 5 MHz, 25 RB")
    print("[]. 10 MHz, 50 RB")
    print("[]. 15 MHz, 75 RB")
    print("[]. 20 MHz, 100 RB")
    band =  input ("masukan pilihan (RB bandwith) : ")
```

Comment: I guess it's because `coverage` is empty, you should at least put a `pass` if you are not going to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def coverage ():
    pass

#fungsi througput
def througput ():

    print("---------------menghitung througput Tower-------------------")

    print ("====Plih band====")
    print("[]. 1.5 MHz, 6 RB")
    print("[]. 3 MHz, 15 RB")
    print("[]. 5 MHz, 25 RB")
    print("[]. 10 MHz, 50 RB")
    print("[]. 15 MHz, 75 RB")
    print("[]. 20 MHz, 100 RB")
    band =  input ("masukan pilihan (RB bandwith) : ")
```

In python indentation matters. Before diving in Python world you should spare some time to read about it. Try doing some basic tutorials like [this](https://www.techbeamers.com/python-tutorial-step-by-step/#tutorial-list)

Comment: just add pass if this want to blank fucntion ?

Comment: @daffafaiz - yes, that's the most common use of `pass`, but it can also be used to create an empty class.

Comment: Yes, just like @palvarez said in his comment. I'll put it in a simpler way: Whenever you start a block in python, it expects the idented block. If you don't want anything in your block, the interpreter gets 'confused'. If you don't want anything in that function you need to add at least one statement in it so the interpreter can identify where that block ends